# Create a shell-escaped POSIX path in macOS

Tags: bash, macos, cocoa, posix, core-foundation

I need to create a string from a full POSIX path (starting at the root), so that it *could* be pasted directly into a Unix shell like `bash`, e.g. in `Terminal.app`, without the need for quotes around the path.

*(I do not actually pass the string to a shell, but instead need it for passing it to another program. That program expects the path in just the form that you get when you drag a file into `Terminal.app`.)*

For that, I need to escape at least any spaces in the string, by prepending them with a backslash. And some more characters as well.

For example, this path:

`/directory/-as"<>' *+`

Would be escaped as follows:

`/directory/-as\"\<\>\'\ \*+`

What's a safe algorithm to perform that conversion? I could escape *every* character, but that would be overkill.

There seems to be no framework function for doing this, so I'll need to do the replacing with string operations.

To be conservative (for the most popular shells), while also avoiding clearly unnecessary escapings, what set of characters should be escaped?

Comment: If this is a swift question, it should be tagged as such. The best answer for how to do this **in bash** is to ask the shell itself to do the escaping for you: `printf '%q\n' "$name"`

Comment: That said, if you want a short, readable, and functional reference implementation, [the Python 3.x `shlex.quote` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/shlex.py#L310-L319) does a good job here. The caveat is that it doesn't guarantee that the output will be only ASCII readable/visible characters; if you're trying to quote something with tabs/newlines/BELs/etc., you'll get tabs/newlines/BELs/etc, just in quotes so a POSIX-compliant shell will treat them as literal.

Comment: ...of course, you could also fork off a shell as a child process. `execlp("bash", "bash", "-c", "printf '%q' \"$1\"", "_", myStringVar, NULL)` is what it might look like in C (output written to stdout and able to be captured therefrom), and that will get you a 7-bit-clean result using only printable ASCII characters (albeit not guaranteed to be supported by all POSIX shells; `$''` is a ksh-and-bash-ism that may be in the standard later, but isn't there yet).

Comment: But if you want an answer that's appropriate for Cocoa or Swift or whatever? Tag for those tools; it's not reasonable to expect folks in she `shell` or `posix` tags to be familiar.

Comment: ("without the needs for quotes around the path" -- single quotes are the *only* foolproof approach; otherwise, you find yourself in a world of hurt with shells that add their own syntax -- for example, `=(hi)` is safe to leave unquoted in a baseline POSIX shell, but in zsh, it runs the program `hi`).

Comment: The edit raises questions around *how* shell-compatible that other program's parsing truly is -- if it's *genuinely* POSIX-shell-compatible, it'll accept quotes, so it sounds like you're asking for output to be quoted for something that's sorta-kinda-like-shell-parsing-but-not; to build a correct answer, of course, one needs to know the format that's *actually* expected.

Comment: If you want foolproof, it also depends on what you are really going to be pasting into.  Consider the filename "-rq".  Perfectly legal, doesn't need any escaping but really bad to paste into certain command lines (prefix with "./" or ".\\" to make it safe, depending on your OS)

Comment: @JeffLaing Good point. I my case, which I failed to explain, the path would always be a full path, with a starting "/". So, basically, my question is: "what chars need escaping when passing an unquoted full path to `bash`?"

Comment: Is the identity of this "other program" something you can disclose? If it's open source, we could either (1) inspect its parser to know the actual rules that need to be followed, this permitting a definitive answer; or (2) fix it to *genuinely* accept all valid POSIX sequences (thus removing the "must not use quotes" restriction).

Comment: It's closed source. As I wrote above, I could determine its rules by trial-and-error. I also know that it can read paths that escape *every* char, and I know it does not like quotes around the path. So, I have my own answer: I had just hoped there'd be a simpler way. After all, Terminal.app generates these escaped paths when dragging files into its window, and that's the algorithm or function I wanted to find and use.

Comment: If you are pasting into a shell, it’s the shells parser you need to worry about, not your target program, so (1) wildcard chars, (2) whitespace (3) redirects & process control, (4) quotes and escapes. Ie, ‘“*?\()<>;|$, etc.  if you are passing to another app in an argv array, then no escapes are required unless it’s screwy.

Comment: Hope that’s clear. You do not need to put escapes into ANY path you pass to another rational process, you need them to get past a command line parser. If your target app has one, you need to know what it’s rules are.

Comment: I wonder if I should just delete this question as it seems to have no use to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Better to put the whole thing in single quotes, rather than adding backslashes to individual characters; then the only character you need to escape is a single-quote present inside the string.

The [Python standard library's implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/shlex.py#L310-L319), provided as an example which can be easily reimplemented in any other language having only basic primitives,  reads as follows:

```
def quote(s):
    """Return a shell-escaped version of the string *s*."""
    if not s:
        return "''"
    if _find_unsafe(s) is None:
        return s

    # use single quotes, and put single quotes into double quotes
    # the string $'b is then quoted as '$'"'"'b'
    return "'" + s.replace("'", "'\"'\"'") + "'"
```

That is to say, the general algorithm is as follows:

- An empty string becomes `''` (a pair of literal single-quotes).
- A string which is known to be safe (though it's safest to not try to implement a codepath for this at all, particularly as shells often implement their own syntax extensions in undefined space) can be emitted bare/unquoted.
- Otherwise, prepend a `'`, emit your input string with all `'`s replaced with the literal string `'"'"'`, and then append a final `'`.

That's it. You don't need to escape backslashes (they're literal inside single quotes), newlines (likewise), or anything else.

Comment: Thanks for making the effort. This is not what I asked, though. I really need unquoted strings, for reasons I don't want to discuss here. I've added objc and swift tags to make it clearer I don't need a Python solution (unless it would call into the CF framework).

Comment: The point of the Python solution was to give you an algorithm you can implement in any language you choose (since you didn't originally have any implementation language tagged). Frankly, you **need** to get into why quotes aren't acceptable if you want to get a truly correct answer; many cases that make quotes obviously break will also make backslashes break in nonobvious ways (how shell command-line parsers interpret backslashes is contextually-dependent), so if you don't disclose the details, you're likely to get an answer that has subtle bugs.

Comment: (Note too that "quoting", in shell, is a character-by-character attribute; do you consider something a "quoted" string if-and-only-if it's *entirely* in quotes? `foo' 'bar` parses to the exact same string as `foo\ bar`).

Comment: I've updated my question again, now simply asking for the set of chars that need escaping. I had asked it differently in the beginning because I had hoped that there would be support in the framework for this.

Comment: Again, though, this set of characters is different between shells -- I already gave you an example that doesn't need escaping in POSIX shells and bash but *does* need escaping for ZFS. There are also characters that only need escaping in bash with optional, off-by-default options (like extglob) enabled. The *safe* thing is to quote absolutely everything (which is why I tend to encourage fixing the issue that prevents you from using quotes); if you try to get away with the smallest possible set of characters, you're playing with fire.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, `Terminal.app` escapes the following non-control ASCII chars when dropping a file name into its window:

> Space
>
> !"#$%&'()*,:;<=>?[]`{|}~

And these are not escaped:

> Control codes (00-1F and 7F)
>
> Alphanumerical
>
> +-.@^_

And here's the code that would perform the replacement:

```m
NSString* shellPathFromPOSIXPath (NSString *path)
{
    static NSRegularExpression *regex = nil;
    if (!regex) {
        NSString *pattern =
          @"([ !\\\"\\#\\$\\%\\&\\'\\(\\)\\*\\,\\:\\;\\<\\=\\>\\?\\[\\]\\`\\{\\|\\}\\~])";
        regex =
          [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];
    }
    NSString *result =
      [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:path
                                      options:0
                                        range:NSMakeRange(0, path.length)
                                 withTemplate:@"\\\\$1"];
    return result;
}
```