# How to convert a classic HFS path into a POSIX path

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, core-foundation

I am reading old files that still use HFS style paths, such as `VolumeName:Folder:File`.

I need to convert them into POSIX paths.

I do not like to do string replacement as it is a bit tricky, nor do I want to invoke AppleScript or Shell operations for this task.

Is there a framework function to accomplish this? Deprecation is not an issue.

BTW, here's a [solution for the inverse operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45085776/43615).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution in Obj-C and Swift as category / extension of `NSString / String`. The unavailable `kCFURLHFSPathStyle` style is circumvented in the same way as in the linked question.

**Objective-C**

```
@implementation NSString (POSIX_HFS)

    - (NSString *)POSIXPathFromHFSPath
    {
        NSString *posixPath = nil;
        CFURLRef fileURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)self, 1, [self hasSuffix:@":"]); // kCFURLHFSPathStyle
        if (fileURL)    {
            posixPath = [(__bridge NSURL*)fileURL path];
            CFRelease(fileURL);
        }

        return posixPath;
    }

@end
```

**Swift**

```
extension String {

    func posixPathFromHFSPath() -> String?
    {
        guard let fileURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                          self as CFString?,
                                                          CFURLPathStyle(rawValue:1)!,
                                                          self.hasSuffix(":")) else { return nil }
        return (fileURL as URL).path
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you also know an answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55381517

Comment: I'm afraid, no. Do you really need Terminal.app? There is `NSTask` or `NSUserUnixTask` (for sandboxed apps).

Comment: Nope, as I wrote in the cursive text of my question, I use Terminal's behavior only as an example. I need to generate these paths to retain compatibility with an older app, for data exchange.

Answer (score 3):

The “reverse” operation of `CFURLCopyFileSystemPath()` is `CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath()`. Similarly as in the referenced Q&A, you have create the path style from the raw enumeration value since `CFURLPathStyle.cfurlhfsPathStyle` is deprecated and not available. Example:

```
let hfsPath = "Macintosh HD:Applications:Xcode.app"
if let url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(nil, hfsPath as CFString,
                                           CFURLPathStyle(rawValue: 1)!, true) as URL? {
    print(url.path) // /Applications/Xcode.app
}
```

Comment: Ah! I had seen CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath but the docs did not make it clear that it could handle a classic HFS path.