# Mac Objective-C convert HFS style paths to POSIX path

Tags: objective-c

While trying the approach suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55383444/how-to-convert-a-classic-hfs-path-into-a-posix-path), working directory gets prefixed instead of path conversion. Leading `:` is `HFS` path does not make any difference.

```
    NSString * ttt = @"Macintosh HD:Users:gautam:code:Help:";
    if (CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)ttt, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false))
    {
        NSString * posixPath = [(__bridge NSURL*)url path];
        // posixPath    __NSCFString *  "/Users/gautamjha/code/Macintosh HD:Users:gautam:code:Help:"
        const char * secondName = [posixPath UTF8String];
       // above does not help either working directory gets prefixed.
    }
```

Comment: The problem *is* solved in the referenced Q&A, you just did not copy the code correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you are passing the **source** type `kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle`, but you want to create the URL from an **HFS** path.

As mentioned in my linked answer the constant `kCFURLHFSPathStyle` is unavailable, you have to replace it with the raw value `1`.

```
if (CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)ttt, 1, false))
```

Comment: `kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle` = 0 is original enum, and enum definition is available and code code fails to compile with integer.

Comment: My bad, I updated the answer. On my machine the code compiles with the integer, but the `if` expression doesn't compile. Please try the code in the linked answer literally.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55383444/how-to-convert-a-classic-hfs-path-into-a-posix-path/?

Comment: @MartinR Actually it is, but as the OP couldn't make to solve the issue according to the linked *here* I wrote an answer.