# How to escape a macOS filesystem URL in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, filesystems, escaping

Imagine I want to:

1. ask the user to enter a file path as a string (which could be something such as `'My' "a/b" folder` which in macOS is an entirely acceptable file name.)
2. create an absolute `URL` based on the string entered in step 1 eg `/Users/john/Desktop/'My' "a/b" folder`
3. do something in a `Process` with that URL, for example run `/bin/mkdir "/Users/john/Desktop/'My' \"a:b\" folder"`*

I'm not sure how to achieve this in Swift. I've searched the `URL` docs and not seen anything to do with macOS's filesystem escaping. I am sure there must be a canonical method to achieve this, and not a series of hopefully-I-covered-the-edge-cases string replacements.

```swift
let pathString = """
/Users/john/Desktop/'My' "a/b" folder
"""

let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathString)

let urlString = "\"" + url.path + "\""

var process = Process()
process.launchPath = "/bin/mkdir"
process.arguments = [urlString]
```

I would like urlString to be something like `"/Users/john/Desktop/'My' \"a:b\" folder"`. With that I could create a command such as:

```
mkdir "/Users/john/Desktop/\'My\'\ \"a\:b\"\ folder"
```

1. This is a hypothetical example that illustrates the issue. Of course I'm not actually trying to create a directory using `mkdir` from within Swift :)

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55383444/1187415 ?

Comment: Why not simply `let urlString = pathString.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: ":")`? The slash is the only "banned" character.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the link. My issue is a little different in that the primary difficulty is creating a string representation of the path which is escaped suitably for use in a command line tool, within double-quotes for safety.

Comment: @vadian Your comment gives me a little more confidence to simply manually escape double quotes, and string-replace any forward slashes (within the filename).

Comment: Starting to think it would be fun to rename my `Macintosh HD` to something like `My "small/ish" SSD` and see how many apps do horrible things lol :)

Comment: @jeff-h: You don't have to escape any quotes when you pass the arguments to Process, only when you invoke a shell.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this
`.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlUserAllowed)`